# Getting property from an Javascript object

Tags: clojurescript

I have such a environment to start from:

```
(defn field-name "blah")

(defn obj (js* "{
                 list: [1,2,3,4,5],
                 blah: \"vtha\",
                 o: { answer: 42 }
               }")
```

How do I get (idiomatic way) blah field using `field name` var?

```
(aget obj field-name)
```

works, but it is intended for arrays (docs say)

Comment: Relevant to this question: https://clojurescript.org/news/2017-07-14-checked-array-access

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`goog.object/get`](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.object.html#get) and I think this is idiomatic way to access the properties.

I would also recommend [binaryage/cljs-oops](https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-oops) that is addressing this very problem.

Comment: And if you need to go deeper, `goog.object/getValueByKeys` is nice:
`(goog.object/getValueByKeys obj #js ["o" "answer"])`  yields `42` and `(goog.object/getValueByKeys obj #js ["list" 2])` yields `3`. Also see http://blog.fikesfarm.com/posts/2017-11-09-avoid-converting-javascript-objects.html